# casting exception through

Tags: .net, exception

I want to get text from literal that is inside  a gridview, i used `databoundliteralconrtrol` for casting.

But when i run the program, exception through

Unable to cast object of type System.Web.UI.LiteralControl to type System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl.
**.aspx code:**

```
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selection">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="check1" runat="server"/>


            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="id7" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("assessid") %>' ></asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qno" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList  AppendDataBoundItems="true"  AutoPostBack="true"     ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem ></asp:ListItem>


        </asp:DropDownList>

        </ItemTemplate>


        <EditItemTemplate>


         <asp:DropDownList    AutoPostBack="true"       ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox31"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>


     </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>




      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="description" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:Literal ID="id6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>' >
         </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text='<%#Eval("description") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>




        </FooterTemplate>


    </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Agree" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:Literal ID="id5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option1") %>' >
         </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" Text='<%#Eval("option1") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>








        </FooterTemplate>


    </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Disagree" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:Literal ID="id4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option2") %>' >
         </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" Text='<%#Eval("option2") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>








        </FooterTemplate>


    </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Strong Agree" Visible="true">

        <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:Literal ID="id3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option3") %>' >
         </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" Text='<%#Eval("option3") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>








        </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Strong Disagree" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:Literal ID="id2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option4") %>' >
         </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" Text='<%#Eval("option4") %>' runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

        </EditItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>








        </FooterTemplate>



    </asp:TemplateField>
```

--%>

```
     <%--   <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:Literal ID="id3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option1") %>' >
            </asp:Literal>
       </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="disagree" Visible="true">
        <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:Literal ID="id4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option2") %>' >
            </asp:Literal>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="strongagree" Visible="true">
        <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:Literal ID="id5" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option3") %>' >
            </asp:Literal>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="strongdisagree" Visible="true">
       <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:Literal ID="id6" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("option4") %>' >
            </asp:Literal>
       </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>--%>

      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" Visible="true">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>

       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="update" CommandName="update" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" Text="cancel" CommandName="cancel" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" Text="DeleteAll"  CommandName="delete" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>

    </FooterTemplate>
```

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" Visible="true">

        <ItemTemplate>

          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton23" Text="delete" CommandName="delete" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>




    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="bdh" Text="insert " CommandName="insert" runat="server" />

    </FooterTemplate>
```

```
</Columns>






            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />




        </asp:GridView>
```

**code behind**

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       string percentage = ((LiteralControl)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to paste code properly formatted, I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try casting to a `LiteralControl` as suggested by the exception message:

```
string percentage =   
    ((LiteralControl)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;
```